# Scala Transformation and action

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I have an RDD List[(String, List[Int])] like List(("A",List(1,2,3,4)),("B",List(5,6,7)))

How to transform them to List(("A",1),("A",2),("A",3),("A",4),("B",5),("B",6),("B",7))

Then action would be reducing by key and generating result like List(("A",2.5)("B",6))

I have tried using map(e=>List(e._1,e._2)) but its not giving desired result.

Where 2.5 is average for "A" and 6 is average for "B"

Help me with these set of transformation and actions.
Thanks in advance

Comment: The Later part I have figured out its like below :-

val rdd_toreduce = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(List(("A",1.0),("A",2.0),("A",3.0),("A",4.0),("B",5.0),("B",6.0),("B",7.0)))
.mapValues(value => (value, 1)) 
.reduceByKey {
      case ((sumL, countL), (sumR, countR)) =>
        (sumL + sumR, countL + countR)
    }
.mapValues {
        case (sum , count) => sum / count
      }
.collect
rdd_toreduce.foreach(println)

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to get what you want. You could use a [for comprehension](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/for-comprehensions.html) as well, but the very first one came up to my mind is this implementation:

```
val l = List(("A", List(1, 2, 3)), ("B", List(1, 2, 3)))

val flattenList = l.flatMap {
  case (elem, _elemList) =>
    _elemList.map((elem, _))
}
```

Output:

`List((A,1), (A,2), (A,3), (B,1), (B,2), (B,3))`

Comment: Thanks for your solution. Thats exactly I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

If what you want is the average of each list in the end, then it's not necessary to break them up into individual elements with a `flatMap`. Doing so with a large list would unnecessarily shuffle a lot of data with a large data set.

Since they are already aggregated by key, just transform them with something like this:

```
val l = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(
  ("A", List(1, 2, 3, 4)),
  ("B", List(5, 6, 7))
))

val avg = l.map(r => {
    (r._1, (r._2.sum.toDouble / r._2.length.toDouble))
})

avg.collect.foreach(println)
```

Bear in mind that this will fail if any of your lists are `0` length. If you have some `0` length lists, you'll have to put a check condition in the map.

The above code gives you:

```
(A,2.5)
(B,6.0)
```

Comment: Thanks Travis, It worked as well. Actually today I faced some interview where they have asked me this in two seperate parts. One to flatmap and another to aggregate but I was unable to achieve first part of it and the next part I was able to do, thats why I have asked it this way.

Answer (score 1):

You can try explode()

```
scala> val df = List(("A",List(1,2,3,4)),("B",List(5,6,7))).toDF("x","y")
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [x: string, y: array<int>]

scala> df.withColumn("z",explode('y)).show(false)
+---+------------+---+
|x  |y           |z  |
+---+------------+---+
|A  |[1, 2, 3, 4]|1  |
|A  |[1, 2, 3, 4]|2  |
|A  |[1, 2, 3, 4]|3  |
|A  |[1, 2, 3, 4]|4  |
|B  |[5, 6, 7]   |5  |
|B  |[5, 6, 7]   |6  |
|B  |[5, 6, 7]   |7  |
+---+------------+---+


scala> val df2 = df.withColumn("z",explode('y))
df2: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [x: string, y: array<int> ... 1 more field]

scala> df2.groupBy("x").agg(sum('z)/count('z) ).show(false)
+---+-------------------+
|x  |(sum(z) / count(z))|
+---+-------------------+
|B  |6.0                |
|A  |2.5                |
+---+-------------------+


scala>
```

Comment: Thanks Buddy. This one is better approach too..!!